# Client VPN Cloudformation Security Groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

I am creating a client vpn in Cloudformation so that my entire VPC setup is contained in a template to duplicate environments. When I have gone to put the client VPN endpoint in I see no way in CloudFormation to associate security groups to my endpoint, which you can do via the console:

[image]

There does not seem to by any way to do this, in any one of the following resource types:

- `AWS::EC2::ClientVpnEndpoint`
- `AWS::EC2::ClientVpnTargetNetworkAssociation`
- `AWS::EC2::ClientVpnAuthorizationRule`

It would really be beneficial if I had a way to do this, I don't want to write a custom resource with a Lambda but that's the only way it currently looks like will work without a resource to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [SecurityGroupIds](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-clientvpnendpoint.html#cfn-ec2-clientvpnendpoint-securitygroupids) in `AWS::EC2::ClientVpnEndpoint`.